# What is the use of the return value of the StringBuilder Append(string...) function?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

The complete syntax of StringBuilder's Append(string s) function (and similar functions) is

```
StringBuilder myStringBuilder.Append(string myString)
```

since `myStringBuilder.Append(string myString)` already adds the string to `myStringBuilder`, I was wondering what the return value is for? 
I have never seen any example code that makes use of the return value.

According to msdn it does not return a new `StringBuilder` instance but a reference to the current builder itself (that would be `myStringBuilder`). 
I just can't think of a scenario when using the return value makes sense at all, why didn't they make the return type `void`?

Comment: You have probably seen a lot of use examples, but did not recognize them

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It means you can easily chain calls together:

```
sb.Append("Foo=").Append(foo).Append("&Bar=").Append(bar);
```

... instead of using several separate statements:

```
sb.Append("Foo=");
sb.Append(foo);
sb.Append("&Bar=");
sb.Append(bar);
```

The fact that it's a single expression means you can also use it in places where you're restricted to a single expression, e.g. field initialization or a return statement. The latter means you can use it for expression-bodied members, too:

```
public override string ToString() =>
    new StringBuilder("x").Append(...).Append(...).ToString();
```

(In many cases using `string.Format` or an interpolated string literal would make more sense, but sometimes `StringBuilder` is the way forward...)

Comment: How stupid of me...I've used StringBuilder like this hundreds of times myself. Abount string.Format: I read that the performance gain of StringBuilder, string.Format and joining strings using "+" varies depending on the number of strings you want to join...

Comment: @sth_Weird: Yes, but I'd normally go with readability rather than performance unless I knew it was performance-critical.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add more value to Jon Skeet's answer, it would be worth to mention that this is a *fluent API design*.

It has its pros and cons, but as Jon Skeet has already pointed out, not only with `StringBuilder` but in many other classes and frameworks, being able to fluently configure or execute things is very interesting.

Maybe the OP has never seen `list.Where(x => ...).OrderBy(x => ...).Select(x => ...).ToList()`. Or Castle Windsor's fluent configuration API: `Component.For<X>().ImplementedBy<Y>().LifeStyleSingleton()`.

That's why `StringBuilder` returns the instance from which `Append` was called: to being able to call other methods *as a chain* which, sometimes, seems to be easier to understand than many separate sentences.

#### About the cons

@Jason asked me for the cons in some comment:

> Matias, What are the cons?

Taken from my own experience, I believe that there're few *cons*, but one of most important ones might be that a *fluent chain* can be harder to debug since you can't go step by step during an interactive debugging session (*actually you can step into and step out... but it's less comfortable than going step by step...*).

Excepting that *con* I find fluent design a good way of implementing auto-documented code since sometimes it's just like reading a natural language sentence and keeps things simple (*to those that have already got used with fluent design...*)

Comment: I would not call it a fluent API design, as one method does not make a fluent interface!

Comment: @IanRingrose Well, once you can call a method from the instance returned by the first method in a chain... it seems to be fluent, isn't it? :\

Comment: Matias, What are the cons?

Comment: Another issue with such a design is that it can make it less clear whether a method returns a pointer to the original object after altering it, or whether it returns an altered copy of the original object.

Comment: @supercat Yeah, you're right. I would add it to the answer but I feel that my answer will end up unrelated to this Q&A... :(

Comment: @supercat I don't know if there's an existing Q&A about what are the pros and cons of fluent api design... Maybe we can open one and mark it as community wiki :D

Comment: Another minor downside is that if one of the calls raises an exception, the stacktrace will be much less informative about which call was the problem. (Or at least, that's true of the Java analogue. I'm not so familiar with the situation in C#.)